# using dual camera in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

### I'm trying to make an app that take pictures and record videos from front and back camera at the same time

I try using flutter,

I used [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) Package,

It worked perfect when using one camera ,

But when I add the second camera ,

The first camera turn black.

This is the [project](https://github.com/oday-awad/liveMoments) on github

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @HamzaKhurshid 
**No**, it's work with some devices

Comment: Did you find any solution  to this?

Comment: @FedeAmura 
No, you can not use the two cameras at the same time,
But in some devices you can.